# Converting Text file to CSV without repeating names in the first column while adding up values in real time

Tags: python, csv, awk

all,

First post on SO so if I am asking a question that has already been answered please let me know and I will delete this post right away.

I am trying to convert a text file that looks something like this:

```
PID 0xA043

FW  119

SER#    HQXXXXXXXXX

V   13544

I   8

VPP -11077

PPW 9

CS  0

ERR 0

LOAD    ON

H19 0

H20 0

H21 23

H22 0

H23 0

HSDS    0

Checksum    1:A000020000148

PID 0xA043

FW  119

SER#    HQXXXXXXXXX

V   11492

I   -8

VPP -11013

PPW 3

CS  7

ERR 0

LOAD    ON

H19 0

H20 0

H21 620

H22 0

H23 0

HSDS    0

Checksum    1:A000020000148
```

.. to a CSV file so that I can display the data in a chart with with either Python and Dash or maybe HTML and JS.

as you can see it's a text file with two columns, one with names and the other one with values the file gets printed every second.

The file is the output of a C "mock" file that I wrote. It prints the the data in the same format as the output of the device I am trying to emulate (basically the output of a Putty that shows the voltages of a charger I'm using)

I am trying to convert this text file to a CSV file, without duplicating the names and adding up the values in the same row (if the names are printed in the first column )or in the same column (if the names are printed in the header).

I have tried with python (CSV,pandas) and AWK but I had no luck so far.

The CSV file that comes out is basically the same file but with commas between the names and values and of course the names in the first column get duplicated every time I run it.

The code that I tried so far in both Python and AWK is really just printing the two columns with a comma in between , this why I didn't post it.

If any CSV or AWK expert can help, I would like to know if this is possible in general or if the text file has to be rewritten before it gets converted to CSV and or if it's possible to do it with just one language.

this is the python I have so far:

```
import csv
import zlib

with open('data.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    lines = in_file.read().splitlines()
    stripped = [line.replace(","," ").split() for line in lines]
    grouped = zip(*[stripped]*1)
    with open('data.csv', 'w') as out_file:
        writer = csv.writer(out_file)
        writer.writerow(('V'))
        for group in grouped:
            writer.writerows(group)
```

Any help is very much appreciated,

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Comment: Thanks, just uploaded my python, and will upload the AWK (shell script) as soon as I figure out where I saved it.

Comment: `cat data.txt | sed -e '/^$/d' | awk '{print  $1 "," $2}'` is this what you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Hi, Ajith-stark! thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it's not. I am trying to write the names ($1) only once and then add the values ($2)  separated by commas everytime time they get printed. The file adds 17 names and values every second and I would like to put them in a CSV file , but writing the first column only once and add the data in the second column in the same row sperated by commas. Is it doable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could proceed like this by collecting data by concatenation in an array:

```
awk '
$1 != "" { a[$1] = a[$1] (a[$1] == "" ? "" : ",") $2 }
END { for (name in a) printf("%s\t%s\n", name, a[name]) }
' data.txt > data.csv
```

Output:

```
FW  119,119
ERR 0,0
Checksum    1:A000020000148,1:A000020000148
H20 0,0
H21 23,620
LOAD    ON,ON
H22 0,0
VPP -11077,-11013
H23 0,0
CS  0,7
HSDS    0,0
PPW 9,3
I   8,-8
V   13544,11492
PID 0xA043,0xA043
H19 0,0
SER#    HQXXXXXXXXX,HQXXXXXXXXX
```

**EDIT**

I have made a version based on @EdMorton answer. I find his answer elegant because it uses another Unix command (`sort`) to handle large files (which follows the Unix philosophy of having a collection of tools which do their job well) and also because it looks somehow more idiomatic. The version proposed below uses only `print` instead of `printf` just to see if it was possible.

The variable `last` is used to avoid having a comma at the end of each line. We have to wait before we output a comma to know if it is the last value of the current line.

```
$ cat tst2.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sort "$1" |
awk '
!NF { next }
$1 != prev {
    ORS = "\n"
    if (last != "") print last
    last = ""
    ORS = " "
    print $1
    ORS = ","
    prev = $1
}
{
    if (last != "") print last
    last = $2
}
END { ORS = "\n" ; print last }
'
```

```
$ ./tst2.sh data.txt
CS 0,7
Checksum 1:A000020000148,1:A000020000148
ERR 0,0
FW 119,119
H19 0,0
H20 0,0
H21 23,620
H22 0,0
H23 0,0
HSDS 0,0
I -8,8
LOAD ON,ON
PID 0xA043,0xA043
PPW 3,9
SER# HQXXXXXXXXX,HQXXXXXXXXX
V 11492,13544
VPP -11013,-11077
```

Comment: This is great!! thank you so much! It works and that's exactly what I needed! Thanks!

Comment: ..also.. I tried to upvote your answer but here on SO, from what I understand, your upvotes don't get displayed unless you have at least 15 reputations.. and I only have 11, I signed up this morning.. but thanks again for the code! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This will work efficiently and robustly even for massive input files whose data is too large to fit in memory at once:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sort "$1" |
awk '
BEGIN { ORS="" }
!NF { next }
$1 != prev {
    printf "%s%s", ORS, $1
    OFS = FS
    ORS = RS
    prev = $1
}
{
    printf "%s%s", OFS, $2
    OFS = ","
}
END { print "" }
'
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
CS 0,7
Checksum 1:A000020000148,1:A000020000148
ERR 0,0
FW 119,119
H19 0,0
H20 0,0
H21 23,620
H22 0,0
H23 0,0
HSDS 0,0
I -8,8
LOAD ON,ON
PID 0xA043,0xA043
PPW 3,9
SER# HQXXXXXXXXX,HQXXXXXXXXX
V 11492,13544
VPP -11013,-11077
```

Comment: What do you mean by getting the wrong output ?

Comment: @Jack edit your question to show the expected output.

Comment: @Ludovic Hi again, I mean that when I run the code above on my terminal , I get a single column (the names pile up). When I run the code below I get the expected result (the names get printed only once and then the values are added in the row.. I will try to add the outputs of both codes to show you .. thanks again for your help.

Comment: @lLudovic, I had not seen your update, sorry about that. Trying the code now.

Comment: @Ed , thanks, sorry I am still figuring out how to operate SO. I added the expected output to my "answer your question. Should delete it and re-post it as an update in my question?

Comment: You might want to edit your original question with additional infos since the answer by @EdMorton and mine both work correctly. That means your own answer does not add something new. Are you running this on Windows ? As you can see, @EdMorton provided a Bash script which invokes the `sort` command to sort your input file before piping it to `awk`. Did you create the Bash script ?

Comment: @Jack delete your "answer" and add all information to your question. Make sure that the expected output you provide is the output you expect from the input you provide, not different output that you'd get from some other input than that shown in your question.

Comment: @EdMorton , thanks I just deleted my "answer" to my question.

Comment: @Ludovic Kuty and  Ed Morton, this is really embarrassing .. now they're both working.. what I did is a simple chmod +x to the file with Ed Morton's code (maybe the sort wasn't working before because of that?). Anyways.. now they both work. Thanks so much!

Comment: Good to hear! If it was not executable you should have get `-bash: ./tst.sh: Permission denied` but anyway it is nice that everything is working ok.

Comment: I accidentally deleted the first comment I made in this comment section (here under ED Morton's code). The one that said that Ed Morton's code wasn't working. It does work now.